# I want to use a free reporting tool like Crystal Reports in React application for my ERP

Tags: reporting, react

Can anyone suggest anything?

I was looking out for Bold reports. Did anyone work on a similar platform?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Bold Reports for free if you or your company is eligible. Check the following link for eligibility criteria,
https://www.boldreports.com/community-license

React Feature tour: https://www.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/react-report-viewer

React Reporting UG: https://help.boldreports.com/report-viewer-sdk/react-reporting/

Online Demos: https://demos.boldreports.com/react/#/report-viewer/product-line-sales

Support: https://www.boldreports.com/support

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anyone  can help me with the report viewer setup and parameters passing techniques?